# How to install Magictricks from recovery mode?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rooting, root-access

I am trying to root my old OPPO F1s following the tutorial on [this link](http://www.droidviews.com/root-oppo-f1s-a1601-and-install-twrp-recovery/).

I am stuck on step two of rooting using fastboot.
When I enter the recovery mode and try to install the Magictricks.zip in my phone storage, it gives me the error message saying installation failed.
I also tried many other tutorials providing different packages and each time I try to install them using recovery mode it just always fails.
Currently, I haven't done anything that I can think of that may result in this failed installation cycle.

Any Idea how to install .zip on Oppo phones in recovery mode?

Also, I can't see SD card option in recovery mode while installing files.How can I get that as in most of the online tutorials and demos people do get this option?
My phone configurations:
Model: Oppo f1s A1601
Ram: 3GB
Android: 6.0
and enough space in both SD card and phone internal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [Magisk](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/com.topjohnwu.magisk) app that I obtained from my friend's Repository which will help you to download Magisk.zip that you'll flash via custom recovery only and you'll be rooted

Note: If you haven't installed TWRP or CWM it won't install the zip. Configuring and using Fastboot are the basics you need to be and to flash the recovery though.

If new to these, read this [guide](https://www.getdroidtips.com/root-twrp-recovery-oppo-f1s/) here and get TWRP recovery from it

Comment: the problem happens when unlocking the bootloader.when enter command adb reboot bootloader or adb reboot-bootloader it just reboots.while it works properly when I enter adb reboot recovery.So I can't just unlock bootloader.

Comment: So that means there's no fastboot support for your phone at all so don't waste your time thinking you never done anything right. The stock recovery won't flash zip packages that have not been properly signed by the manufacturer. Therefore your only hope to root this phone relies on one click apps. Try your luck out of them though I tend to see that Kingoroot is a powerful one

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to root it using fastboot because I don't trust these applications.Is Kingoroot safe?

Comment: It will never harm your device. What you'll install after that is what might harm it in rooted mode. I even know flashing supersu.zip from recovery is what might harm your device as compared to one click tools which I have never had problems with. SuperSU.zip might lead to bootloop on some devices because it modifies the system. Magisk is a better way of a zip to root your device since it never touches your system. But since you have no fastboot, just try kingoroot

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. I truly appreciate your help and guidance.

Comment: Welcome always buddy.